# VScode can't open git-rebase-todo

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-rebase

I set vscode as my git editor using
git config --global core.editor "code --wait", this works fine for the commit flow but not for the interactive rebase flow where vscode just can't manage to open the git-rebase-todo file.

I went into the folder where the file exists and tried to open from there using code git-rebase-todo but that didn't work either ( same error ). But other editors could open it and using "cat" on the file confirmed it's there and has the right content to be displayed.

EDIT: I can't find the original post I read about this but it started working for me overnight, the author of the original post had the exact same thing happen, maybe vscode needs to restart for the rebase to work or maybe a computer restart needs to happen.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what is not clear in my explanation, I literally wrote that VSCODE can NOT OPEN the file GIT-REBASE-TODO. Would adding a screenshot of VSCODE saying he CAN'T OPEN the file GIT-REBASE-TODO help you out ? Anyways, I was about to do that but for some strange reason it works today and it didn't work tomorrow, maybe vscode has to be restarted for the config to work, I don't know, in any case I will edit the post because some other post I read about this exact same issue also had his config start working overnight.